# Resetting an Autocompletetextview with a custom arrayadapter and filter

Tags: android, filter, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I'm having trouble with an autocompletetextview.  When I first start the app the autocompletetextview work's as expected, I can type in 'm' and get a list of all restaurants which start with 'm'...

[image: Autocompletetextview with 'm']

Then when I type more, 'mark', the list updates as expected...

[image: Autocompletetextview with 'mark']

However the problem happens when I delete the text and start over with a different letter, the autocompletetextview no longer updates with other letters...

[image: Autocompletetextview with 'n']

Any idea why clearing the text doesn't allow me to "start over" with the filtering?
Here is my ArrayAdapter code...

```
 class AutoLocationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Location> implements Filterable{
    private ArrayList<Location> locations;
    private ArrayList<Location> allLocations;
    private Filter filter;

    public AutoLocationAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Location> locations) {
        super(context, layout , locations);
        this.locations = locations;
        this.allLocations = locations;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return locations.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_locations_auto_row, null);
        }

        Location l = locations.get(position);

        if (l != null) {

            TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.frag_location_auto_name);
            TextView town = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.frag_location_auto_town);

            if (name != null){
                name.setText(l.getName());
            }
            if (town != null){
                town.setText(l.getTown());
            }
        }

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null) {
            filter = new LocationFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

    private class LocationFilter extends Filter{

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (charSequence == null ||charSequence.length()==0) {
                results.values = locations;
                results.count = locations.size();
                Log.v("!!!", "cleared filter");
                locations = allLocations;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else {
                ArrayList<Location> nLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();
                for(Location l : locations){
                    if(l.getName().toUpperCase().startsWith(charSequence.toString().toUpperCase())){
                        nLocations.add(l);
                    }
                }
                results.values = nLocations;
                results.count = nLocations.size();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            if (filterResults.count==0) {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
            else{
                locations = (ArrayList<Location>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (charSequence == null ||charSequence.length()==0) {
  results.values = locations;
  results.count = locations.size();

  Log.v("!!!", "cleared filter");
  locations = allLocations;
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

So, basically when you've already filtered, you're saying here that `results.values = locations` which corresponds to the **previous** filtering. So if the new filtering pattern don't match the set that you previously filtered, it won't show anything, what you're basically experiencing. You have to first set `locations = allLocations` and then set the `results.*` params:

```
if (charSequence == null ||charSequence.length()==0) {
  Log.v("!!!", "cleared filter");
  locations = allLocations;
  notifyDataSetChanged();

  results.values = locations;
  results.count = locations.size();
}
```